# custom html boxes in tree layout with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image]I have a requirement where I have to develop a tree layout similar to what is given by d3.js tree layout. But I want html boxes with custom content rather than just nodes. I have spent lot of time trying to find if its possible with d3.js but I am stuck at this point of time and unable to proceed.

The data will be dynamic

It does not have to be d3.js if there are any other viable solution/framework available. But the functionality expected is similar to what is provided by d3 ie- expanding, collapsing nodes.

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you want a more detailed response I would suggest being more explicit with what you are hoping to accomplish. Maybe make a diagram of what you want it to look like, and what you want to be in these html elements. The function works by mapping SVG circle elements based on the input hash. Have you tried reworking the code to append your desired HTML element instead? Is the data you wish to display fixed or dynamic?

Comment: @Damon - Please see the picture. Appreciate your response. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do can be achieved by using [ForeignObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject).

The basic scenario is this one:

```
<foreignObject requiredExtensions="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <p>Some text</p>
  </body>
</foreignObject>
```

Here is a more complete example : http://jsfiddle.net/thudfactor/bK6VD/

You use `d3` to generate the `foreignObject` content based on your data.