# D3 draw n circles in a tree

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image]
I have the following data, using which i plotted a d3 tree, where each node is a rectangle. Now, I want to draw n circles on each rectangle(where n is value of `'minor'` in each node(see data), but not sure what's the easiest way to achieve this.

```
// Data
{
"minor": 1,
"critical": 0,
"children": [{
    "minor": 2,
    "critical": 0,
    "children": [{
        "minor": 3,
        "critical": 0,
        },
        {
        "minor": 2,
        "critical": 1,
        },
        {
        "minor": 1,
        "critical": 1,
        }]
    }]
}

// JS
  const nodeEnter = node.enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .style('font-size', '12px')
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
  })
  .on('click', click);

  // Add Rectangle for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .attr("width", function (d) { return d.children || d._children ? 150 : 350 })
    .attr("height", 70)
    .attr('stroke', '#ccc')
    .attr('stroke-width', '1');
```

Comment: What does "drawing a circle on a rectangle" mean? Should it be in the rectangle, or outside? How are the circles positionned?

Comment: I've added an image for example, the small red/green circles in the box is what i am able to draw by `.append('circle')` but i'm not sure how to do it n times, where n is `d.data.minor` ... Irrespective of the positioning, i just want to understand the 'HOW'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [custom html boxes in tree layout with d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35644344/custom-html-boxes-in-tree-layout-with-d3-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`d3.range`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#range) to create an array of a specific length. Then you can treat this array just like any other d3 data structure.

```js
const nCircles = 5;
const radius = 8;
const padding = 2;

d3.select('svg')
  .selectAll('circle')
  .data(d3.range(nCircles))
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', function(_, i) {
    return radius + padding + i * 2 * (radius + padding);
  })
  .attr('cy', radius + padding)
  .attr('r', radius)
  .attr('fill', 'darkred');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Alternatively, you can use a fully ES6 solution, but it's unnecessarily complex:

```js
const array = new Array(nCircles).fill(undefined).map(function(_, i) { return i; });
```

From your data, I gather that each node has the attributes `minor` and `critical`. Now, to update the balls of your newly inserted nodes, you can use

```js
nodeEnter
    .selectAll('.minor')
    // Here you take the data from the node and transform it into
    // the data for the circles. This is what makes it generic.
    .data(function(d) { d3.range(d.minor))
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .classed('minor', true)
    .attr('cx', function(_, i) {
      return radius + padding + i * 2 * (radius + padding);
    })
    .attr('cy', radius + padding)
    .attr('r', radius)
    .attr('fill', 'darkyellow');

// And for critical messages:
nodeEnter
    .selectAll('.critical')
    .data(function(d) { d3.range(d.critical))
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .classed('critical', true)
    .attr('cx', function(_, i) {
      // To position it next to the minor circles, we need to
      // know how many there are
      const nMinorCircles = d3.select(this).select('.minor').size();
      return radius + padding + 2 * (radius + padding) * (i + nMinorCircles);
    })
    .attr('cy', radius + padding)
    .attr('r', radius)
    .attr('fill', 'darkred');
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you're a life saver. Can you direct me how to use this `d3.range()` with each element of tree, i.e. with nodeEnter

Comment: Apologies for asking you to do my homework, but i'm just starting with js/d3 .. and this thing is bothering me since 3 days now. I used https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd as a starting point for the tree

Comment: I've updated my answer with some more context. I also really recommend [this article](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) and [this article](https://medium.com/@bryony_17728/d3-js-merge-in-depth-a3069749a84f), which explain data flows and joins in d3